# Ternary operator confusion in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

can someone explain me how this line of C# code is calculated?

```
int myInt = false? true ? 0 : 1 : 2; // ans = 2
```

Comment: Oh dear god my eyes.... This code should be re-written (full stop)

Comment: Add parenthesis for the line to be more reable: `int myInt = false ? (true ? 0 : 1) : 2;` and it'll be easy to find why

Comment: my recommendations: 1. study the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). 2. replace your true and false with variables, play around with their values, and try to figure it out yourself. 3. [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Let's add *parenthesis* for the line being more *readable*:

```
int myInt = false ? (true ? 0 : 1) : 2;
```

Now let's compute the values. For *inner* `?:` we have

```
(true ? 0 : 1)
```

Which equals to **0**. Then *outer* `?:` will be

```
int myInt = false ? 0 : 2;
```

which equals to **2**

Comment: One could also add that `false` always evaluates to `false` so the only part that makes sense in the expression is `2`, so it can be shortened to `int myInt = 2;`